# Adjusting font size for fake perspective

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, loops, paths

I'd like to add text on the paths on the left side with font size continuously adjusted from `\Huge` to `\tiny` to achieve a perspective like effect. The font size steps shouldn't be `\Huge`, `\huge`, `\LARGE`, … `\tiny`, but font size should take values between the listed sizes too.

[image]

I'd like to achieve something like this:

[image]

And put it on the paths on the first figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
% BOTTOM_1
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\tiny|~~Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dona abstulit meis~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (373.7500, 406.2500) -- (586.2500, 406.2500);

% BOTTOM_2
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\scriptsize|~~commendet' permansit in. Adhibitis amor est~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (366.6667,413.3333) -- (593.3333,413.3333);

% BOTTOM_3
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\footnotesize|~amet constanter determinatio debitis torporis~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (358.5714,421.4286) -- (601.4286,421.4286);

% BOTTOM_4
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\small|~quin. Suam ad quia ei quoque sed dominum oculo~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (349.2308,430.7692) -- (610.7692,430.7692);

% BOTTOM_5
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\normalsize|~capillos quam aniculae morsque nutricem valeas~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (338.3333,441.6667) -- (621.6667,441.6667);

% BOTTOM_6
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\large|~Apollonium contigit cum. Taliarchum in modo~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (325.4545,454.5455) -- (634.5454,454.5455);

% BOTTOM_7
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\Large|~invenit iuvenem patre ad quia illum ille~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (310.0000,470.0000) -- (650.0000,470.0000);

% BOTTOM_8
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\LARGE|~illum decidat quam dicentes multa prima~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (291.1111,488.8889) -- (668.8889,488.8889);

% BOTTOM_9
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\huge|~donatoris substantiae. Esse deprecor~||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (267.5000,512.5000) -- (692.6609,512.5000);

% BOTTOM_10
\path [decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text={|\Huge|~cum magna Dianam Interposito eum.||},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}}]
        (237.1429,542.8571) -- (722.8571,542.8571);

% LEFT_6
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,280.7209) -- (940.1713,332.1807);

% LEFT_5
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,368.2026) -- (940.1713,368.2026);

% LEFT_4
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,455.6843) -- (940.1713,404.2245);

% LEFT_3
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,543.1661) -- (940.1713,440.2464);

% LEFT_2
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,630.6478) -- (940.1713,476.2683);

% LEFT_1
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,718.1295) -- (940.1713,512.2902);

% BOTTOM_LEFT
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,805.6112) -- (940.1713,548.3120);

    % BOTTOM_RIGHT
\path[draw, cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (1300.3902,548.3120) -- (1557.6894,805.6112);

% path3109
\path[cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}},draw=black,line
  join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt] (682.8721,805.6112) --
  (682.8721,280.7209);

% path3111
\path[cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}},draw=black,line
  join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt] (940.1713,332.1807) --
  (940.1713,548.3120);

% path3113
\path[cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}},draw=black,line
  join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt] (940.1713,548.3120) --
  (1300.3902,548.3120);

% path3126
\path[cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}},draw=black,line
  join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt] (940.1713,332.1807) --
  (1300.3902,548.3120);

% path3902
\path[cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}},draw=black,fill=black]
  (940.9426,440.5375) -- (940.9426,333.5818) -- (941.8770,334.0818) .. controls
  (943.1031,334.7380) and (1296.8461,547.1006) .. (1297.0831,547.3227) ..
  controls (1297.1831,547.4165) and (1217.0924,547.4932) .. (1119.1038,547.4932)
  -- (940.9426,547.4932) -- (940.9426,440.5375) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit #1**

Using `\foreach` in TikZ I've managed to get almost the desired effect for one character.

[image]

```
\newcommand\myfontsize[1]{\fontsize{#1}{10}\selectfont}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {22.82086,...,6.80565}
    {
        \draw (-\x, 0) node {\myfontsize{\x}a};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But still I don't know how to apply this for a series of characters (e.g. a sentence), and put the text on the path.

---

**Edit #2**

Reading further the TikZ manual I found out that I can iterate through two variables simultaneously. This allows me to use different font sizes for each character in the iteration.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i/\char in {22.82086/a,18.8170575/b,14.813255/c,10.8094525/d,6.80565/e}
    {
        \draw (-\i, 0) node {\myfontsize{\i}\char};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However I have to specify the step size explicitly in the `\foreach` loop. So this raises the question that how can I calculate the step size depending on the number of characters I want to print.

Comment: I have no automated solution but \scalebox{<factor>}{content} from the `graphicx` package allows you to scale in small steps.

Comment: I don't think changing font size is a good idea. As seen in your example, you're getting different design sizes with vastly different glyph shapes, which doesn't suit the "perspective" idea at all. Hence, I second @UweZiegenhagen s idea of using `\scalebox`. Maybe `\resizebox` is even better because you can give the desired length.

Comment: Have a look at [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/). It's able to draw TeX on almost any surface, see the gallery, e.g. the [Klein bottle](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/Klein.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer for my problem at the question [Text spirals with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88762/8844). All credit goes to the original answer.

After including the following macro you can use the `text path start scale=2.4` and `text path end scale=0.5` key-value pairs in the decoration options.

```
\makeatletter

\let\pgf@lib@dec@text@dobox@original=\pgf@lib@dec@text@dobox%

\def\pgf@lib@dec@text@dobox{%
    \pgf@lib@dec@text@dobox@original%
    \ifpgfdecorationtextalongpathscaletext%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@lib@dec@text@endscale+(\pgf@lib@dec@text@startscale-\pgf@lib@dec@text@endscale)*\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance/\pgfdecoratedpathlength}%
    \setbox\pgf@lib@dec@text@box=\hbox{\scalebox{\pgfmathresult}{\box\pgf@lib@dec@text@box}}%
    \fi%
}
\newif\ifpgfdecorationtextalongpathscaletext
\def\pgf@lib@dec@text@startscale{1}
\def\pgf@lib@dec@text@endscale{1}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
    text path start scale/.code={%
        \pgfdecorationtextalongpathscaletexttrue%
        \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@startscale{#1}%
    },
    text path end scale/.code={%
        \pgfdecorationtextalongpathscaletexttrue%
        \def\pgf@lib@dec@text@endscale{#1}%
    }
}
```

See `LEFT_1` path in the question and replace it with the following:

```
% LEFT_1
\path[decorate,%
    decoration={text along path,%
    text path start scale=2.4,
    text path end scale=0.5,
    text={vso nbl dsfn klijvb sodvn},%
    text align={fit to path stretching spaces}},%
    cm={{0.55521796,0.0,0.0,0.55521796,(-142.0,95.56731)}}]
    (682.8721,718.1295) -- (940.1713,512.2902);
```

The oputput will be:

[image]