# Text spirals with hebrew

Tags: hebrew, spiral

I would like to obtain a final result like in this post:
[Text spirals with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88751/text-spirals-with-tikz)

But I incur in 2 problems

- 1. The solution does not work with Hebrew text
- 2. It does not work with long chunks of text, even latin text (I have over 1000 words and I'm thinking of using a tiny font)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  decoration={
    reverse path,
    text effects along path,
    text={\texthebrew{מאימתי קורין את שמע בשחרית. משיכיר בין תכלת ללבן. רבי אליעזר אומר, בין תכלת לכרתי. וגומרה עד הנץ החמה. רבי יהושע אומר, עד שלש שעות, שכן דרך בני מלכים לעמד בשלש שעות. הקורא מכאן ואילך לא הפסיד, כאדם הקורא בתורה
}},
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      character count=\i, character total=\n,
      characters={scale=1-\i/\n}
    }
]
\draw [decorate] (0,0) 
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\r=(\i/2000)^2;}] in {0,5,...,2880}{ -- (\i:\r)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A spiral with a few words may be funny visual effect, but forcing someone to read a thousand words in a spiral seems a cruel method of torture.

Comment: For a visual effect. Not for reading. Please see the example in the page that is linked. The center of the spiral is not meant to be read.

Comment: Yeah, that is the fine part of the torture. Not only cause neck pain with readable part, also eyestrain in the less readable part, and finally frustrate the reader's curiosity with the unreadable part. Smile to note that this is not a serious comment: `:)`