# How to create a tikz picture, with a non-infinite distance viewpoint

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Hi I am trying to create a planar tikzfigure, but would like to tilt the plane. Most advice I could find gives a perspective that has the viewpoint in infinite distance.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,x={(-0.2cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
        \draw(0,0)[color=magenta] circle (1);
        \draw(-2,-2)[color=blue] circle (0.6);
        \draw(1.5,-1.8)[color=red] circle (0.75);
        \draw(-1.8,2.5)[color=green] circle (0.6);
        \draw(1.5,2)[color=orange] circle (0.75);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How could I make this more "star wars text" like with things closer appearing larger.

Comment: TikZ handles text differently from graphics.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84621/adjusting-font-size-for-fake-perspective?s=1|0.2685

Comment: It would be easier to create a rectangular pdf with standalone and run it through a graphics editor.  Perspective transformations are pretty standard.

Comment: Do you know free software that can do such a perspective transformation on a pdf?

Comment: GIMP is the one I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is GIMP's perspective transformation of a page (see [Size and position of boxes in title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0686#273885))

[image: demo]