# Distorting tikz picture to look like it's a picture from a book?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

Can a `tikzpicture` be distorted to look like it's a picture from a book in an easy way (not exporting to pdf, printing, taking picture and using said picture)?

something like:

```
\tikz[distorted=jpg] \draw (0,0) --(1,1);
```

Edit:

So

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{document}
```

creates a very beautifull line, that looks like it's in vector graphics format (which is hard to see on a screenshot):

[image]

What i then want is an easy way to distort the tikzdrawing so it looks like a picture taking with a real bad camera more so than vector graphics?
Why would one want to uglyfi ones buatiful tikz figures? For fun! (the distorded=jpg in the original post was a pseudo way of telling tikz to make the drawing look as ugly as a jpg picture, full of loss).

Comment: Please, can you post a complete MWE?

Comment: @Sebastiano Tried to do this,  hope it makes sense, it's not for any real purpose, mostly a fun/challange thing like the coffee package

Comment: Not sure to understand it, but perhaps these questions and answers are related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36552/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334341/1952

Comment: try the `random steps` path decoration, section 24 of the pgf manual, so something like `decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}`; Don't forget to load the  appropriate library `decorations.pathmorphing`. For a real jpg distortion, you would have to cut the pictures into cells and distort those separately; Try looking at the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319172/gimp-like-perspective-transform-in-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Related, insofar as distorting a font, rather than a `tikzpicture`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122970/simulate-printing-imperfections-and-defects-with-tex

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, it's really cool. Is there also a way to add a blurry lens effect, so it looks like it's a picture taken with an old camera?

Comment: You are probably better off creating in standalone image and editing it with a graphics editor.  They have many more effects than LaTeX.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312238/how-to-create-a-tikz-picture-with-a-non-infinite-distance-viewpoint/312959?s=1|0.1241#312959

Comment: @JohnKormylo You're right, but it seems like a fun thing to do in LaTeX XD