# How to insert a detailed front page?

Tags: front-matter

I have to write a professional document and I'd like to insert a front page with a lot of basic informations about me (address, phone, etc.). How could I do that? This is a very basic MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Dossier de candidature}
\author{My name}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Article class does not normally produce a title page.  My advice is to not use \maketitle and simply format the page the way you want.  You might use \thispagestyle{empty} and \setcounter{page}{0} and start the next page with \maketitle.

Comment: Is there another Latex class I could use to that purpose?

Comment: Report class will produce a title page, but it won't add all the details you want.  There is a package which allows you to modify the title page produced by \maketitle, but what is the point of using \maketitle if you have to modify it?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex and (for fun) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312238/how-to-create-a-tikz-picture-with-a-non-infinite-distance-viewpoint/312959?r=SearchResults&s=6|26.4439#312959