# How to remove parts of image based on tikzpicture shape behind it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics

I am trying to remove parts of my image so it looks like it is inside of a shape (tikzpicture). I don't have an idea how to do it, I guess that my LaTeX code (see below) has to be thought over.

This is my output right now:
[image]
And this is how it should look like:
[image]
This is my LaTeX Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\vspace*{-2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[color = red] (-3.5cm, -0.5cm) node{}
-- (-3cm,-5cm) node{}
-- (\paperwidth,-6cm) node{}
-- (\paperwidth,0.5cm) node{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.28\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.29\paperwidth]{Test}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Now if you really want to be fancy, store the coordinates of the corners and use a graphics editor (like Gimp) to apply a perspective transformation.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312238/how-to-create-a-tikz-picture-with-a-non-infinite-distance-viewpoint/312959?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.9088#312959

Comment: The perspective solution is interesting. Thanks for your comment, John! 

Comment: Please don't answer in the question, add a new answer

Comment: Thank you for your note! I now posted it as a new answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you could do with a `clip` and a `preaction` to fill the clipped area

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    % Without clip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[preaction={fill=red}] (0,-2) -- (5,-4) -- (5,4) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
    \node[inner sep=0] (image) at (2,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % With clip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[clip,preaction={fill=red}] (0,-2) -- (5,-4) -- (5,4) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
    \node[inner sep=0] (image) at (2,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Without clip

[image]

With clip

[image]

Comment: Very nice, just what I've been looking for. Thank you! (Y)

Comment: @owmal you are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** based on BambOo's answer, I've updated the code above to be suited for my example. It looks just like what I've wanted to create. Here is the new code, if that helps anyone:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\vspace*{-2.5cm}

\hspace*{-3.5cm}\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip,preaction={fill=red}] (-3.5,-0.5) -- (-3.5,-5) -- (\paperwidth,-6) -- (\paperwidth,0.5) -- cycle;
\node[inner sep=0] (image) at (3,-3) {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{Test}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: It looks almost like this]